# Cordova SocialSharing Plugin - Facebook Callback Error

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've been using the SocialSharing plugin in my Cordova app for many months and it's been working great, and I rely on its FB Sharing's callback functionality to track if people shared a post.

However, I just discovered that the callback stopped working correctly on iOS 8.1.

When I click on the "Cancel" in the FB dialog popup, the plugin calls the success function and returns "true" as the parameter. Previously it would call the success callback, but pass in a "false" parameter, so I'd be able to determine if it was "Cancel" or "Post" button that the user clicked on.

I have tried updating to the latest version of the plugin, but it still fails on my iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.

If I test it on my iPad running iOS 7, the Cancel button works fine. Can  someone please advise on how to resolve it?

Below is the SocialSharing plugin official page:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Thank you.

Comment: Does the callback have only true or false states? I have noticed that if an item is successfully shared, you normally get back the post id. I am not  sure what the plugin is returning, but if you are able to check for the post id, it might work.

Comment: Thanks Bangdel, apparently this is a bug with Facebook's own app interfering with external plugins by returning the wrong true/false result. It's been reported and recognized by them a few weeks back, yet they have not released a fix for it. I just found the bug report here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved as of today, when Facebook updated their app. To resolve the problem, user needs to update the Facebook app.

Further details are available at this Facebook bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/

Comment: Does the same fix applies for  twitter?

Comment: I didn't encounter problem with Twitter sharing... apparently the Facebook sharing problem is caused by Facebook app end's technical error in returning the result, not a fault of the Cordova plugin.

Comment: this is also fixed by updating twitter Thanks for your post

Comment: This issue is again reproduced in my iphone 6 which uses IOS 9 
i have updated the facebook but no luck with the fix

Comment: Hmm, that's bad... seems like they don't even properly test such critical functions. Perhaps you can create a new bug report at their Developers page... the old report is marked as fixed and their team may not take notice of it if you comment there. Please let me know how it goes, it surely affects my app too but I don't have iOS9 so I have no way of testing it at the moment. Thank you.